# how to create v-model custom component in Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am having problems with the two-way binding of a custom component in Next. Maybe I'm making a silly mistake somewhere. I would be grateful for any help

**#Custom Component *Input.vue***

```html
<template>
    <input :value="modelValue" @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)" class="input" type="text">   
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props:{
        modelValue:String,
    },
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import '@/assets/_shared.scss';

.input{
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #cecece;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
</style>
```

**#Page *index.vue***

```html
<template>
    <section class="new-appeal">
        <form class="new-appeal-form">
            <label class="new-appeal-form-item">
                <Input placeholder="Appeal" v-model.trim="cashier_name"/>
            </label>
            <Button class="submit">Creare appeal</Button>
        </form>
    </section>
</template>

<script>


export default {
    layout:'main',
    data:function(){
        return{
            cashier_name:''
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

as you can see I'm trying to do two-way data binding, but unfortunately it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vue 2 you the default v-model value is just `value` and in order to update the value you have to emit `input` event. You can't use `update:modelValue` in vue 2.
you should use this way,

```html
<Input placeholder="Appeal" v-model.trim="cashier_name"/>
```

in your custom Input component

```html
<template>
    <input :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)" class="input" type="text">   
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['value']
  }
</script>
```

Comment: `emits` is [related to Vue3](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/emits-option.html#emits-option) and hence Nuxt3 and is not available in Vue2.

Comment: `You can't use update:modelValue in vue 2`, you can totally do that in Vue2. As shown in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70166841/8816585).

Answer (score 2):

This is working great and is following the conventions.

`index.vue`

```html
<template>
  <section class="new-appeal">
    <form class="new-appeal-form">
      <label class="new-appeal-form-item">
        <Input v-model.trim="cashierName" placeholder="Appeal" />
      </label>
      <Button class="submit">Creare appeal</Button>
    </form>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  layout: 'main',
  data() {
    return {
      cashierName: '',
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

`Input.vue`

```html
<template>
  <input
    :value="cashierName"
    class="input"
    type="text"
    @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
  />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Input',
  props: {
    cashierName: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

---

Otherwise, you could have it as following too (I'm still renaming `cashier_name` to camelCase btw)

`index.vue`

```html
<template>
  <section class="new-appeal">
    <form class="new-appeal-form">
      <label class="new-appeal-form-item">
        <Input v-model.trim="cashierName" placeholder="Appeal" />
      </label>
      <Button class="submit">Creare appeal</Button>
    </form>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  layout: 'main',
  data() {
    return {
      cashierName: '',
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

`Input.vue`

```html
<template>
  <input
    :value="cashierName"
    class="input"
    type="text"
    @input="$emit('update:cashierName', $event.target.value)"
  />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Input',
  // https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#model
  model: {
    prop: 'cashierName',
    event: 'update:cashierName',
  },
  props: {
    cashierName: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your professionalism, have a nice evening, you helped me a lot

Comment: Прости мужик что не тебе отдал правильный ответ, хотя по факту именно ты решил мою проблему. Просто спасибо огромное

Comment: @MiyRon hehe, no issues man. Glad your issue is solved. Enjoy your day! :)